# Cannot make negative matrix in OpenCV/Java

Tags: java, opencv

I'm working on a project with OpenCV, and at some point I need to apply a 2dFilter in an image using this kernel:

```
-1, -1, -1;
-1,  9, -1;
-1, -1, -1
```

in C++ i did this:

```
Mat kernel = (Mat_<char>(3,3) << -1, -1, -1, -1, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1);
```

and it worked fine. But now I need to do the same in Java, and I can't make a Mat object with negative numbers. I'm doing this:

```
Mat m = new Mat();

m.create(3, 3, 0);

m.put(0, 0, -1);
m.put(0, 1, -1);
m.put(0, 2, -1);
m.put(1, 0, -1);
m.put(1, 1,  9);
m.put(1, 2, -1);
m.put(2, 0, -1);
m.put(2, 1, -1);
m.put(2, 2, -1);
```

and the matrix goes like this:

```
0, 0, 0; 0, 9, 0; 0, 0, 0
```

I really think this is something very stupid, but I couldn't find anything to help me.
Could anyone give me some enlightening?

Thanks!

Comment: What happened when you tried it? What was the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
m.create(3, 3, 0); // 0 for type == CV_8U == unsigned char.
```

well, that won't work. if you want to put negative values into it, choose a *signed* type.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what I get for copy/pasting the code =/